# Unity C#: change what a button does via a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

what I want to do is to change the parameters of the buttons On click event(for example if the script(GETFromYTS.DisplayMovies) wants a string change that string). have not seen any good answers.

the "GetfromYTS.displaymovies" code:

```cs
public void DisplayMovies(string[] movieUrls)
    {
         //create text objects with the movie URLs
    }
```

IDE is Jetbrains Rider

EDIT 1: new problem, how do I change the text of the button?

EDIT 2: the first problem solved. answer selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html), you can use `button.onClick.AddListener(function);`.

The other functions (like removing one or more functions already associated with the button) are listed [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.ButtonClickedEvent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from daniel's answer, i'd like to add that in your onclick method you could thrown an unity event: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html

This has some editor support, so in your editor you can call functions of other gameobjects.